# send file with post, then upload with ftp

Tags: php, ftp

This is a very basic question since I do not properly understand the underlying concepts of the different protocols. Please be indulgent.

I can upload files to my site with FTP using Filezilla. Now I'm developing a user interface for sending data to update a database and files (photos) to be saved in a directory. I send this data with `POST` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50136542/1726522)). I get the file, but cannot save it to the destination directory performing

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['PhotoToUpload']['tmp_name'],"../../Photos/".$file_name);
```

I think is because of permissions (currently 755). Since I can currently upload with Filezilla FTP (so I understand I have the permissions to do that),

**my question is**:

Is bad practice (or conceptually wrong) to take the temp file created after the `POST` and load it with a FTP code like the following (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18718321/1726522))?

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "myftp.co.uk";
$ftp_user_name = "myusername";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypass";
$destination_file = "../../Photos/";
$source_file = $_FILES['PhotoToUpload']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: So why don't you change the permissions?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I don't know how to do that. I've found things like `sudo chmod 77 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs` but don't even know _where_ to write those commands (and of course do not know the language).

Comment: So ask your server administrator to do that for you.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl OK, thanks, I'll do that, and keep on with `move_uploaded_file`.